# Subgroup of $S_{2n}$ that sends evens to evens and odds to odds.

Tags: permutations

I got this question in the exam:
$T_{2n}$ is the subgroup of $S_{2n}$ that sends even numbers to even numbers and odd numbers to odd numbers, for example:
$(2 4 6 8)(1 3 5)$ is a permutation in $T_{2n}$.
what is the index of $T_{2n}$ in  $S_{2n}$ ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $T_{2n} \cong S_{n} \times S_{n}$.

Comment: The index is a [famous number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)...

Answer (score 1):

OP here, sorry but can't comment yet (not enough reputation)

This is what I did, please correct my mistake:
Order of $S_{2n}$ is $(2n)!$

Order of $T_{2n}:$ I figured there are $n!$ options for the evens and $n!$ for odds, but since these permutation are equal $(2\;\; 4\;\; 6\;\; 8) = (4\;\; 6\;\; 8\;\; 2)$ I figured, I should divide by $n$ both for evens and for odds. So I got:
$$\frac {(2n)!}{(n-1)!\times (n-1)!}$$

Comment: This answer is correct. If you are the OP (why a different username?) it's OK to answer your own question. Do learn the little $\TeX$ you need to format your questions and answers on this site.

Comment: My bad, I posted the question as a guest instead of my actual account.
are you sure this is correct? most of my friends answered like lhf's answer below

Comment: My bad - @lhf is right. You don't divide by $n$ since you're counting the permutations, not how to represent them as cycles.

Comment: alright, thanks alot to both of you

Comment: You should try [merging your accounts](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), then you will be able to comment on your question and edit it.